# VGA capture card for linux

Tags: linux, video-capture, v4l2, vga, uvc

I am looking for a "VGA capture card for linux", that captures VGA input from remote computer in such a way that I may be able to use V4L2 to capture the feed.  Kindly suggest some.

Answer (score 0):

Datapath has a good reputation and supports Linux:

http://www.datapath.co.uk/video-capture-cards/capture-card-features

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should get a VGA to hdmi adapter, because all of the capture cards nowadays use hdmi. I just got one made by “Avedio Links” that seems to work just fine on debian linux. I have to record everything to boost some lawsuit I have against a couple knucklehead billionaires.

Anyway, it’s pretty easy with VLC player— just make sure to use analog TV input and set cache to about 1 ms. Default is 300, but setting it to zero will not help as much as setting it to 1ms. Everything happens in microseconds, and you need a little cache to utilize your RAM, since the feed comes straight through USB 3.0. 1 ms is not noticeable.